# On using ConditionalExpression inside Integrate vs. getting the result, then applying Assuming on result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, conditional

I thought at first that

```
sol = Integrate[ ConditionalExpression[ integrand, conditions],....]  (1)
```

Is equivalent to and should give the same answer as

```
sol = Integrate[ integrand ,....];
Assuming[ conditions, Simplify[sol] ]   (2)
```

But sometimes they do not give the same result. I am finding (2) is more reliable.

Here is an example

```
ClearAll[c, t, w];
integrand = Exp[I w t]/(c + I*w);
cond      = {c > 0, t < 0};
sol = Integrate[ConditionalExpression[integrand, cond],{w,-Infinity, Infinity}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Applying `Simplify` to the above does nothing. I tried `FullSimplify` on the above but it seems to take forever, so stopped it.

Now compare method (2) result

```
sol = Integrate[integrand, {w, -Infinity, Infinity}];
Assuming[cond, Simplify[sol]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And applying `FullSimplify` instead of `Simplify` returns this result quickly

```
 Assuming[cond, FullSimplify[sol]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the above little experiment shows that using `ConditionalExpression` inside `Integrate` did not help. It seems to have actually made the situation worse in this example.

So, is there a reason or advantage to using method (1)  vs. method (2) with `Integrate`? Is my assumption that (1) and (2) should be equivalent wrong?

Mathematica 11.3 on Windows.

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused, but is there a reason to assume that integrating a `ConditionalExpression` should result in a result which assumes that the condition is met? Your second input (with `Assuming`) explicitly says, "perform this integral under the assumption that `cond` is true". The first, though, is just integrating a statement which says, "*if* `cond` is true, *then*..."

Comment: The premise of equivalence is not correct. A conditional expression does not carry any implication that the conditions are met. (This is really just to confirm the point raised, and nicely elaborated, in a prior comment by @BenKalziqi.)